# firebase-collection won't refresh data on firebase-auth login, if location doesn't include user value

Tags: polymer, firebase-authentication, firebase-polymer

If **location** (firebaseURL) in code below includes the **user** value (like auth.uid), then firebase-collection **data** will refresh on-login from firebase-auth. I am using Polymer 1.6.0

```
<firebase-auth id="auth"
      location="[[firebaseURL]]"
      provider="{{provider}}" 
      params="{{params}}"
      user="{{user}}">
    </firebase-auth>

    <firebase-collection
      location="[[firebaseURL]]"
      data="{{messages}}">
    </firebase-collection>
```

This is because on-login from firebase-auth the **user** value changes and that changes the **location** value, refreshing the **data** coming from firebase-collection.

However, if the **location** path doesn't include the **user** value, the **data** will not show up on-login, and you will have to refresh the page for that to happen.

The only way I have found so far to work around this limitation is a bit hackish.

I have to modify the html code for firebase-collection as follow:

```
<firebase-collection
      location="[[_location(user)]]"
      data="{{messages}}">
    </firebase-collection>
```

Adding the _location() function like this, to force the firebase-collection **data** to refresh and show up on-login

```
  _location: function(u){
    // hacking - to trigger the update firebase-collection/document on-login / on-user-change
    return this.user ? this.firebaseURL : "";
  }
```

It works but it doesn't look right to me.

Is there a better way, a more polymeric way?

Thanks

## AskPolymer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`dom-if`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-if) to stamp `firebase-collection` conditionally on `user`:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[user]]" restamp>
  <firebase-collection
    location="[[firebaseURL]]"
    data="{{messages}}">
  </firebase-collection>
<template>
```